# www-data in sudo with mount

Tags: php, shell, exec, sudo

Unable to launch the mount command via php and exec

Of course :
The file sudo toto.sh works
and
www-data is allowed in sudoers to ALL so all processes
www-data ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

toto.sh:

```
Machine = "L1069"
machine="L1069"
mount -t cifs //$ipaddr/c$ /mnt/pc-backup/$machine -o   "vers=2.0,username=agent-back-ws,password=Bcth2,ro,iocharset=utf8
,noserverino"
```

In the go.php file:

```
$outputShell=passthru('sudo cat /etc/passwd');
$output=exec('sudo  /var/www/html/toto.sh 2>&1');
var_dump ($output);
var_dump ($outputShell);
```

When I run php go.php (as root) I get:

```
<pre> </ pre> string (0) ""
```

and mount is done  and the content of / etc / passwd is displayed

---

On the other hand via the browser I launch www / go.php so in www-data: I get:

```
string (0) ""
```

no mount and the content of / etc / passwd is displayed

Why the mount does not work is the problem seems the script with php7 and latest Debian version ...

```
Help !!!!!!! works in debian 8 and php 5.5
> L106529
passe dans gosuite.sh ....
Machine : L106529 -  IP: xxx.xxx.250.185
Commande passee :  /bin/mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.250.185/c$ /mnt/pc-backup/L106529 -o "vers=2.0,username=agent-backup-ws,password=BcK312Eth2,ro,iocharset=utf8,noserverino"
execve("/bin/mount", ["/bin/mount", "-t", "cifs", "//xxx.xxx.250.185/c$", "/mnt/pc-backup/L106529", "-o", "vers=2.0,username=agent-backup-w"...], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0

[pid 26704] mount("//xxx.xxx.250.185/c$", ".", "cifs", MS_RDONLY, "ip=xxx.xxx.250.185,unc=\\\\xxx.xxx.2"...) = 0
[pid 26704] capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 26704}, {CAP_SYS_ADMIN, CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_SYS_ADMIN, 0}) = 0

not works in debian 9 php 7 :

L106529
passe dans gosuite.sh ....
Machine : L106529 -  IP: xxx.xxx.250.185
Commande passee :  /bin/mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.250.185/c$ /mnt/pc-backup/L106529 -o "vers=2.0,username=agent-backup-ws,password=BcK312Eth2,ro,iocharset=utf8,noserverino"
execve("/bin/mount", ["/bin/mount", "-t", "cifs", "//xxx.xxx.250.185/c$", "/mnt/pc-backup/L106529", "-o", "vers=2.0,username=agent-backup-w"...], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5565ff8c5000
pid 14506] capget({version=0 /* _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_??? */, pid=0}, NULL) = 0
[pid 14506] gettid()                    = 14506
[pid 14506] open("/proc/sys/kernel/cap_last_cap", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 14506] read(3, "37\n", 7)          = 3
[pid 14506] close(3)                    = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the script from your "root context", you do not have to use the full paths to the executables you use.

You should use the full path to the binary in your scripts.

```sh
Machine = "L1069"
machine="L1069"
/bin/mount -t cifs //$ipaddr/c$ /mnt/pc-backup/$machine -o   "vers=2.0,username=agent- 
back-ws,password=Bcth2,ro,iocharset=utf8
,noserverino"
```

and

```php
$outputShell=passthru('sudo /bin/cat /etc/passwd');
$output=exec('sudo  /var/www/html/toto.sh 2>&1');
var_dump ($output);
var_dump ($outputShell);
```

To identify the correct path, use `whereis mount` and `whereis cat`

Comment: yes, thank you, but I had already tested with complete paths and it still does not work. How to do ? Security issues PHP7 or latest Debian verion? Thank you

Comment: in summary how to launch a php script that contains the mount command and that works? In php 7 and debian 9.9 Thanks